# Why the change in phrase with the morning blessings?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, blessing, words, hebrew

In the morning blessings, there is a small but seemingly important variation in word usage across three blessings.

In the blessing about the distinction between day and night, G-d is described by the attribute, הנותן לשכוי.

Again, in the blessing concerning giving strength to the weary, G-d is described as, הנותן ליעף כח.

But in the blessing for the Torah, it says simply, נותן התורה.

In the first two blessings, the *specific Heh* is used, which emphasizes a specific *Giver*.

In the third blessing the *specific Heh* is not used. Strictly speaking, that means a nonspecific *Giver*, one among many.

Has anyone seen a discussion of what is being brought out by this variation? If so, what is it?

Comment: נותן התורה has an implicit article on the first word as well, it’s just that the phrase is written as *semichut*. It’s the equivalent of הנותן של התורה

Comment: Just to widen the context, we say מלביש ערומים, פוקח עיוורים, and מתיר אסורים with no specific Heh on the doer, nor on the thing done to, and we say רוקע **ה**ארץ על המים with the specific Heh on the things done to (just like נותן **ה**תורה).